# How to merge two pandas dataframes based on a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

There are two pandas dataframes as follows:

```
df1:

col11  col22  col33

abc    25     36
bcd    55     96
cdf    15     19
abc    74     26
```

and

```
df2:
        
col01  col02  col03
    
name1    x     346
name2    g     926
name3    t     179
name1    k     286
```

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` based on a dictionary that this dictionary's keys are `col11` and its values are `col01` as follows:

```
mydict = {'abc': 'name1', 'bcd': 'name2', 'cdf': 'name3'}
```

My expected is:

```
df1:

col11  col22  col33 col01  col02  col03

abc    25     36    name1    x     346
bcd    55     96    name2    g     926
cdf    15     19    name3    t     179
abc    74     26    name1    x     346
```

How can I merge this two dataframes?

Comment: In your example, the rows of df2 are already aligned with the rows of df1. For example, the 4th row has 'abc' in df1 and 'name1' in df2, which match according to your dictionary. So you could just append the columns of df2 onto df1 and be done. Is this also true for your real data?

Comment: If it's not true, how do you want to decide if row 0 of df1 should be matched up with row 0 or row 3 from df2?

Comment: Please provide the expected output (do you want all combinations of matches or only the one to one in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mapped Series as key in `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1['col11'].map(mydict), right_on='col01')
```

Output:

```
  col11  col22  col33  col01 col02  col03
0   abc     25     36  name1     x    346
1   abc     25     36  name1     k    286
2   abc     74     26  name1     x    346
3   abc     74     26  name1     k    286
4   bcd     55     96  name2     g    926
5   cdf     15     19  name3     t    179
```

For a one-to-one merge in order:

```
(df1.assign(n=df1.groupby('col11').cumcount())
 .merge(df2.assign(n=df2.groupby('col01').cumcount()),
        left_on=[df1['col11'].map(mydict), 'n'],
        right_on=['col01', 'n'])
)
```

Output:

```
  col11  col22  col33  n  col01 col02  col03
0   abc     25     36  0  name1     x    346
1   bcd     55     96  0  name2     g    926
2   cdf     15     19  0  name3     t    179
3   abc     74     26  1  name1     k    286
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question and inserted my expected result.